# streamlit, st_aggrid, possible to do enableColumnGroup=True to perfectly mimic pivottables?

Tags: pivot-table, streamlit

https://streamlit-example-app-interactive-table-streamlit-app-mt9qg6.streamlit.app/

allows to group by rows

would it be possible to group by columns *as well* ? it would then completely fill pivot tables role

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [docs for streamlit-aggrid](https://streamlit-aggrid.readthedocs.io/en/docs/GridOptionsBuilder.html?highlight=grouping#st_aggrid.grid_options_builder.GridOptionsBuilder.configure_default_column), it looks like you can do `builder.configure_default_column(groupable=True)`